# I am not able to build the job on jenkins from github

Tags: java, github, jenkins

I am new to jenkins and I was trying to create a job in jenkins. I had pushed my project to github and had supplied the path of github server to jenkins but when I am trying to build the job it is showing an error and not geting build....please help in solving that...

This is the exception that I am getting---

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\Rishi\.jenkins\jobs\Spring\workspace
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC # 
timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

Comment: you are getting a time out. Please check if repository is reachable from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to fetch from a GitHub repo, no need to use ssh (which would require the proper private/public ssh keys to function).

Use the https url, which does not require any authentication (for pulling)

```
 https://github.com/rishi1020/SpringMVC
```

Comment: The problem with ssh and Jenkins is that often Jenkins doesn't use the same account as the one where you set up your ssh keys. Since you don't need authentication for pulling a public GitHub repo, you might as well skip ssh and use HTTPS.